# Redirect some pages to url and some to another in the same domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My question title may not be appropriate but you i can try to explain the problem i am, running through here in the description :

What i want is that one page of the site should be redirected to a particular url and the rest to another one.

i.e. 
www.mysite.com/industries/accounting.php should redirect to www.mysite.com/new-industries/accounting

where as 
www.mysite.com/* should point to www.mysite.com/newsite

I hope i make sense here. issue is that whenever i try to put in a rule it gets looped for the specific page. any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^industries/accounting\.php$ /new-industries/accounting [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!newsite/).*)$ /newsite/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```